# Java Oracle connection falls down

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I'm implementing school project. We have to create own ORM in Java EE and Oracle. I've already tried two ways of database connection:

1. DriverManager.getConnection(DSN, USER, PASSWORD);
2. Context initContext = new InitialContext();
   Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
   this.dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/isets");

One method works worse then other to me. I have an Entity (table row) and this Entity has a property containing a list of another Entities. When I'm trying to print these entities out, sometimes it looks like the database connection falls down, because some entities aren't load. Almost everytime a few of them are not printed out, sometimes everything is ok (it's not predictable which ones won't be printed out or when it will be ok).

When I'm using the first method of connection, it works for very few database queries. If I'm trying to select, for example 10 objects from database (in 10 queries), there will be shown an exception of Oracle server. On the other way, when I'm using the second method, there are more issues. The first one is that almost everytime when I run the application, it's loading infinitely (at least 10 minutes). Sometimes it loads properly, but according to the first method, much more "subentities" aren't load properly.

I'd like to use connection pool, but I have no idea where the problem could be. I followed this ["HOW TO"](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g), but it doesn't want to work :-(.

Here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/ISETS-TOMCAT">
    <Resource name="jdbc/isets"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"

        testWhileIdle="true"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testOnReturn="false"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"

        maxActive="15"
        maxIdle="5"
        maxWait="-1"

        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        logAbandoned="true"

        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
        username="SYSTEM"
        password="admin"

        defaultTransactionIsolation="SERIALIZABLE"  />
</Context>
```

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>isets.controllers.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>ISETS Oracle pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/isets</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

and here is the code to establish a connection:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/isets");

connection = dataSource.getConnection();
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could you help, please? Thanks, bye.

Comment: Both your context.xml and web.xml seem all right, as well as your code (at first sight!)  Maybe you could show us the connection management inside your entities?

Comment: Also, please show us the exception you get.

Comment: Are you running out of resources (e.g max number of cursors existed) because you aren't closing result sets and freeing connections properly after you use them, perhaps? Showing the exceptions you get would really help.

Comment: Here is the message of the exception: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Comment: Then yes, that is what you're doing. You need to check all your code looking for connection leaks...

Comment: Ups, and what should I looking for exactly? In what places should I close statements and connections? Should it always be in try-catch-finally block? Is it enough to close connections or is necessary to close statements too? Thank you again.

Comment: And @Alex Poole, please, put your comment as an answer. For now, I don't know exactly, how to solve it, but it looks like a correct answer. Thank you

Comment: It's too vague to be an answer at the moment. See if [any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ora-12519) help. This might be close enough to one to be closed as a duplicate but not sure which yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE changes that are made from one connection may not be visible from another connection. I would try removing this setting.

Comment: Removing SERIALIZABLE level of isolation doesn't work and unfortunately it's the requirement of the project, but thank you.

Comment: What is the exception?